# How to import a default file with JSPM, by requiring the folder like node require()

Tags: import, require, systemjs, jspm

I've been trying JSPM for few days, but couldn't find an easy way to `import module from folder`.

As described in the node documentation [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) for the method, it is possible to require a folder. This would resolve to *folder/index.js* if the file exists.

Is there a way to do that with SystemJs/JSPM ?

Comment: You have to add package config to SystemJS config file for every folder you want to require like that, for example `packages: { 'your-folder': { main: 'index.js' }, ...}`

Comment: See also [Please add support for auto-importing index.js files(closed)](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1433)

Comment: I'm building a react+redux app, and I'd want to be able to group all files related to a specific component into a folder, then expose an object containing all the public functions for this component (component, actions, reducer ...).  

I though about creating an index.js file importing all those files then exporting only the things I want to be public.  
This allow to have an 'API' for my component, and other components could import parts if needed (ie actions).  

The thing is, applying a main to each and every component doesn't seems right.  

Do you see another solution ?

Comment: Well there is one way, but it requires to have package.json file for every single component (which is not unusual - people publish many small components on npm all the time). If you have package.json files already for all components with proper `main` in them, and the only thing you need is `main`, you can use [packageConfigPath](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/767#issuecomment-139515090)  (see the comments that follow the one linked for better examples).